# PhantomJS build with video features

Tags: phantomjs

I use Windows 8.1 and my computer has a 64-bit processor. I'm trying to build PhantomJS so it can support video/audio features, but when I am building it I get this error.

I tried [phantomjs doesn't support html5 video tag](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10839).

```
python build.py

c:\strawberry\c\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.4.3/../../../../i686-w64-mingw
32/include/dvec.h:837: error: '_mm_cvtpd_ps' was not declared in this scope
c:\strawberry\c\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.4.3/../../../../i686-w64-mingw
32/include/dvec.h: In function 'F64vec2 IntToF64vec2(const F64vec2&, int)':
c:\strawberry\c\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.4.3/../../../../i686-w64-mingw
32/include/dvec.h:838: error: '_mm_cvtsi32_sd' was not declared in this scope
mingw32-make: *** [qhash.o] Error 1

ERROR: Failed to build PhantomJS! Configuration of Qt Base failed.
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots. Copy the text from the terminal and insert it in your question.

Comment: @StefanBecker thank you for your comment i edited it now.